# How can I run offline database usage in Blazor WebAssembly-PWA?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, indexeddb, blazor-webassembly

I have a `Blazor WebAssembly ASP.NET Core hosted - PWA` application and want to run it offline. The database is currently built with SQLite and EF-Core. Is it possible to add offline functionality? I have read about `IndexedDB` but don't actually know how to implement that into the project (client-side). Or is there any NuGet Package for this support?

The functionality I want to bring into the project is - **tracking local changes and fetching them to the DB when its online again.**

Comment: Ah, hosted is not webassembly, you know. And your database (sqlLite) is not exactly webassembly either. Also sqllite would not really handle syncing- that requires programming.Easy answer thus is NO. Hosted model runs on the server, not using WebAssembly.

Comment: @TomTom It is WebAssembly Client-Side but in addition with the Server-Side. So at runtime the server is building up the client and they can communicate via Http Requests. The "offline" DB should be in a way in the client project and fetch via Http request to the server DB. The only problem is I don't know how to do that ^^..

Answer (score 6):

I've created a library that provides bi-directional offline sync for mobile clients that should do the job: https://github.com/stefffdev/NubeSync

Especially handling conflict resolution when multiple clients did change a record can become tricky, so you could use that as a starting point.

I plan to create a blazor wasm offline sample and blog about it soon.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking at the sample for Blazor WASM and it's confusing me. It seems to call the server via http client directly from your Razor pages. Does this provide a persistent cache for when an app is offline for multiple days (allowing user to continue working) then syncs once online?

Comment: Hi, you are right, in the provided sample I'm just calling REST calls without any offline capability.
Currently I am not working on a Blazor offline client since we are not developing Blazor apps right now.
A few infos on that you can find here https://github.com/stefffdev/NubeSync/issues/22

Answer (score 2):

You can try this package. This is a Blazor library to work with IndexedDB DOM API

https://github.com/amuste/DnetIndexedDb

Answer (score 1):

check [This example, uses javascript to store locally in the browser](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/CarChecker)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using event sourcing to solve this problem. It deals well with syncing occasionally connected clients as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35514230). It means dropping entity framework and probably rearchitecting your entire persitance tech stack, so it is far from ideal. But if you plan on building a large complicated system, this is the way to go.